# Applying Look and Feel on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, joptionpane, substance

I'm using a LAF (Look and Feel) with Substance. It's perfect, except for JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.

I want it to inherit the LAF's appearance, it gets its custom background from Windows, but not for the bar (at the corner, where you see the closing "X").

Is it that LAF doesn't have a defined style for JOptionPane? Or it's possible to extend it?

Comment: you need to show some code, how do you set the LAF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I used it, but I'm almost sure if you follow the examples in [Substance look and feel's docs](http://insubstantial.github.com/insubstantial/substance/docs/api/SetUseConstantThemesOnDialogs.html) you'll get your JOptionPane fully styled.

Search for `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` in the page and you'll see its use on  INFORMATION/ERROR/WARNING/QUESTION_MESSAGE.